# Обьекто-ориентированный код на PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Здравствуйте, я java разработчик и недавно пришлось сесть на бэкенд и писать на php. Но мне не нравится процедурный стиль кода

```
mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Мне нравится так

```
$result -> num_rows;
```

Можно ли так писать со всеми функциями или есть ограничения? А вообще хочу максимально приблизить php код в java, может есть генераторы? Или любой другой способ?

Comment: конкретно для БД рекомендуется использовать PDO

Comment: `может есть генераторы?` - есть. `Можно ли так писать со всеми функциями ` - можно. Делаешь классы и методы и пишешь. `хочу максимально приблизить php код в java` -  в чём?

Comment: Вообще-то с версии 5 php очень ООП-язык. Я сам пересел с явы, так что прочитать один мануал и все будет понятно. Очень рекомендую Зандстра М. Объекты, шаблоны и методы программирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что под максимальным приближением PHP кода к Java имеется в виду желание иметь возможность переиспользовать знакомые по Java разработке ООП практики и принципы построения и проектирования архитектуры приложений. В таком случае, советую начать осваивать какой-либо современный PHP фреймворк (если хочется что-то похожее на Java, имхо ближе всего будет Symfony).
Современные подходы к написанию server side приложений на PHP на деле не сильно отличаются от других языков со схожей ООП моделью (например Java), есть конечно идеоматические отличия, есть своя инфраструктура, но принципы все же общие.

К слову об инфраструктуре. Вы же на Java когда пишите, вы используете сторонние библиотеки, пакеты и пр.? В PHP инфраструктуре есть замечательный пакетный менеджер `composer` (https://getcomposer.org/). Всякий раз, когда вам "не нравится процедурный стиль" - знайте, что кто-то уже скорее всего сделал приемлимую объектную обертку для нужного вам функционала. Более того, эта обертка вероятно еще и покрыта тестами, имеет открытый код и поддерживается сообществом. Все, что остается, найти нужный пакет, подключить его в свой проект и пользоваться.

Конкретно для работы с БД есть множество хорошо зарекомендовавших себя решений: тут и мощные ORM, такие как Doctrine (которая, к слову, сделана по подобию Hibernate из мира Java), и более простые ORM, которые лучше подойдут для проектов небольшего размера (например, реализующие паттерн Active Record), и, если ORM вам ни к чему, различные query builder`ы, просто обертки над PDO и пр.

Answer (score 0):

объектно-ориентированный интерфейс http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php
или PDO